# How to pass .phtml file variable to another module .phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am new in the magento. If anyone have idea how to do this then please let me know.
I have two files in different module in in that two .phtml file will be there.
From First .phtml file to another .phtml file i want pass array variable
I am not getting how to pass that.

First file path as follows with php variable:

```
/var/www/html/MyProject/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Lof_CustomerMembership/templates/customer/membership/transactions.phtml
```

In this file i have $transaction variable that i want to send another info.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard\Address $block */

$helper = $this->helper("Lof\CustomerMembership\Helper\Data");
$transactions = $block->getTransactions();
$address=$block->getPrimaryBillingAddress();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerId =$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
 $activeOrNot="";
?>
```

Another file path will be:

```
/var/www/html/MyProject/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Magedelight_SMSProfile/templates/account/dashboard/info.php
```

In the info.php file i want that $transactions array variable

Anyone have idea how to do this then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your getTransactions() function inside in your block. so just reuse the block for your another phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Three options,

1. just copy your function from transactions block to info block, all related variables and constructions too.
2. From info block, create object from transactions block and this object to create getTransactions() function
3. Simply call it directly using

   $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\ModuleName\Block\ClassName');

   echo $blockObj->getTransactions();